# Error boostraping juju maas juju-db already running

Tags: juju, maas

I'm trying to bootstrap a juju maas environment.   I get the error   "job is already running:  juju-db".  I destroy the environment run again and get the same thing.  It brings up a maas node and does all kinds of provisioning but then fails.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please add the output from /var/log/maas/maas.log to your question to help us help you! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are all of your nodes registered in MAAS  set to PXE boot (boot from the network)? I guess that you might be booting off of HDD and coming back to an already running Juju bootstrap machine.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that MAAS didn't previously shut down the node (which it can't if it's powered via Wake-On-LAN) so whilst you thought you were booting up the node from scratch, it was actually already on and hence juju-db was already running.

I asked a similar question here, the responses to which may help: [MAAS/juju not cleaning up nodes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488396/maas-juju-not-cleaning-up-nodes)